# How to call and implement C++ function in Android SDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have installed Android NDK so I can use C/C++ functions in my Android application.
Consider we have a C++ function in `Cpp_add.h` header file like this:

```
int Cpp_add(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

I want to use this function to add two integers when an 'add' button is pressed in my Android application. Consider I want to call this function in this 'add' button's `onClick` method. Could any of you write something like a little tutorial for using this function and the C++ header file in Android application? I checked most of the questions about using C++ functions in Android, but they only explain general use of NDK or using C++.

Comment: Have you looked through the sample code that comes with the NDK?

Comment: Could you tell where I can look at it? Thank you.

Comment: I looked at the examples, but they are complicated, I just need the 'add' example so I can understand it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Follow the steps for "Exploring the hello-jni Sample".  These steps create a working application that calls a c++ function from Java code.

Once you have that working and understand how to create an application with NDK support, you can see how the c++ function calls work.  Look at the source in /samples/hello-jni/hello-jni.c for the prototype of the c function, and samples\hello-jni\src\com\example\hellojni\HelloJni.java for the code that calls the c++ function.